# Node.JS call an asynchronous function on Node server exit

Tags: node.js

Regardless of whether an exit is graceful or not, is there a way to run a MySQL (asynchronous) function before the program closes in Node.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's graceful then yeah. If it's something like `uncaughtException` then it's not recommended.

According to node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events):

> `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` have default handlers on non-Windows platforms that resets the terminal mode before exiting with code 128 + signal number. If one of these signals has a listener installed, its default behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).

I.e. you can add your own handlers to those two events, and then just call `process.exit()` when you're done.

Also from the same page:

> `uncaughtException` should be used to perform **synchronous** cleanup before shutting down the process.